# 1000px width layout. May I have problems using it?

Tags: layout, grid

I'm designing 12 columns site using Bootstrap. I have a quite crowded layout (can't simplify it further), so I want to use a 1000px wide layout (exactly [this one](http://gridcalculator.dk/#/1000/12/20/0)), instead of using classic grids like 940/960/980. Have you ever used a 1000px wide layout? Are you aware of problems concerning it? For example: poor experience on tablets, interferences with scroll bars, or other problems?

Answer (score 3):

What about using Bootstraps built in responsive design? The "large" size easily accommodates what you need, and the responsive element could be just turned off.

I think 1000px is very reasonable considering horizontal scrollbars. the 940px is designed for 1024x768 screens. It's a safe range, but what is your audience? If it's modern tech consumers, they probably won't be on something that small, except for mobile devices. But then, a 1000px wide layout probably isn't the end of the world for them. Things scale down on tablets so likely the UI will be a bit smaller before it just has to scroll.

I wouldn't worry too much about a 1000px width to be honest. Figure out what your target audience is. Or, just test it. Fire up XCode and run it through the ipad and iphone emulators.

Answer (score 2):

The 960 grid was designed for 1024px (minimum) screens and much of its popularity stems from being early on the scene.  And it was also divisible by 3 and 4, which suggested versatility I suspect.

But these days with responsive/adaptive techniques there's no single grid metrics that must be adhered to.  Many people just make a custom grid for the particular job.

Answer (score 1):

There will be not problem on tablets because sites are re-sized on it. I think you can use this grid with with no worry for that.

There are more frameworks for >1000px widths because today small group of users still use monitor with 1024 width resolution.

On the other hand it all depends what resolution have your users (it can be checked in Google Analytics).

By the way, if you have a mess in your layout, a bigger width will not help a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this grid: [1140](http://cssgrid.net/) and at this article [finger friendly](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/21/finger-friendly-design-ideal-mobile-touchscreen-target-sizes/) web design.  I believe 20px gutters are to small for finger friendly web. Most of the problems with the sizes can be overcome with media queries. Take a look at [Google blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/responsive-design-harnessing-power-of.html) where they are recommending using responsive web design.

Comment: Thanks for the boomark! finger friendliness is really important in responsive web sites. The article is well written. In particular the difference between finger pad e finger tip.

Comment: Yeah the article is very good, hope it helps with the problems that you are facing.